# How to display local notification when the app is not in the recent history of the device using Xamarin Crossplatform

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to display local notification when the app is closed and also app is not in the recent history of the device.How can I do this.

Please help me..

Here is my code `MainPage.cs`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
        {
            GetData();

            return true; 
        });
    }

    public void GetData()
    {
        IAlarmReceiver _local = DependencyService.Get<IAlarmReceiver>();
        _local.LocalNotifications("Xamarin", "Hello world");
    }

    private void btn_Click_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }
}
```

Here I call the notification method in every 5 seconds.

Here is my AlarmReciever.CS

```
    public void GetNotification(string Title, string Text)
    {
        Intent _intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        const int _pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent _pintent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, _pendingIntentId, _intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Application.Context)
       .SetContentIntent(_pintent)
       .SetContentTitle(Title)
       .SetContentText(Text)
       .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
       .SetAutoCancel(true)
       .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

        Notification _notification = builder.Build();
        NotificationManager _notificationmanager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService)
            as NotificationManager;

        _notificationmanager.Notify(0, _notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  ACR Notifications Plugin for Xamarin this will display the local notification when app is closed.

Example **await CrossNotifications.Current.Send("Happy Birthday", "I sent this a long time ago", when = TimeSpan.FromDays(50));**

Answer (score 0):

If you tested your program using the debugger the notification will be terminated with the rest of your application as soon as you close it.

I tested your code (assuming _local.LocalNotifications should be _local.GetNotification) and it worked, when the app is started on the device without the debugger.

**EDIT**

To display the notification all x minutes, use a ScheduledJob

Add a StartJob Method to your IAlarmReceiver inteface and its implementation

```
public void StartJob()
{      
  var builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1234, new ComponentName(Android.App.Application.Context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ScheduledJob))));
  builder.SetPeriodic(15L * 60L * 1000L); // <- change the intervall

  var jobInfo = builder.Build();
  var jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.JobSchedulerService);
  jobScheduler.Schedule(jobInfo);
}
```

This method starts the ScheduledJob (defined in the android project)

```
[Service(Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
public class ScheduledJob : JobService
{
    public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters @params)
    {
        new AlarmReceiver().GetNotification("Hello World!", "Xamarin");
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters @params)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Replace

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
    {
        GetData();

        return true; 
    });
```

with

```
DependencyService.Get<IAlarmReceiver>().StartJob();
```

Comment: Actually, I also want to display the notification in every x minutes, if the app is not in the recent history of the device.

Comment: This can be achieved with the JobScheduler (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), on newer android version the minimum timespan between 2 calls is around 15 minutes